# browsersync + http2 + compression over https://localhost

Tags: node.js, gulp, gzip, browser-sync, http2

Trying to init browsersync with https, http2 and gzip, but can never seem to get them all to play nicely together

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var compression  = require('compression');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist",
            middleware: [compression()]
        },
        httpModule: 'http2',
        https: {
            key: "/path/to/localhost.key",
            cert: "/path/to/localhost.crt"
        }
    })
})
```

I can get http2 to work without compression, and compression to work without http2, but never both at the same time... The error I get is

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Doing the same thing using express was successful

```
var express      = require('express');
var http2        = require('spdy');
var serveStatic  = require('serve-static');
var compression  = require('compression');

var credentials = {
    key: "/path/to/localhost.key",
    cert: "/path/to/localhost.crt"
};
var app = express();
app.use(compression())
app.use(serveStatic('./dist', {
    'extensions': ['html'],
    'maxAge': 3600000
}))
var httpsServer = http2.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(8888);
```

But no joy using browsersync

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try putting the server option last?  WTH.

Comment: @Mark, tried that, didn't work

Comment: compression doesn't work with h2 (yet). See [expressjs/compression#122](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/122)